# I'm trying to make custom share option in flutter but i have no idea how to make it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, share

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGK1m.png)

I'm trying to make custom share option in flutter but i have no idea how to make it in flutter

Comment: check this package https://pub.dev/packages/share

Answer (score 0):

make your custom bottomsheet and share content by social_share package